# pg_dump of postgresql pod with no terminal access as it's a prod env

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, openshift, pg-dump

So I want to take pg_dump of postgresql running on pod(openshift). I was thinking to create a cron job which would ssh into postgresql pod and run the pg_dump command. But cronjob actually created it's own pod and execute the command in it's own pod. any idea how can we create a .bak file/take backup of postgresql whose terminal we cannot access.

Comment: `pg_dump` is a client side program. You can run it from any computer that is able to connect to the database.

Answer (score 1):

thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, it worked. I created a dummy postgresql pod in `dev namespace` where I had access to terminal and executed the `pg_dump` command as follows
`pg_dump --username=username --host=host  --port=port   postgres > pguat.bak`

it created the `pguat.bak` file. Restored it with following command to the new pgsql pod.

`psql --username=username --host=host --port=port postgres < pguat.bak`